# Formatting the values of fields in a Django form

Tags: django, templates, forms, filter, format

I have a Django form whose fields are sometimes blank, sometimes have a default initial value, and sometimes populated by values from an associated model.  In the latter two cases, I have DecimalFields that are going out to the template like so:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="10.00"/>
```

The issue is that I want to be able to format that value attribute with template filters, or some equivalent.  For instance, for the above input I'd like to use the floatformat filter so that instead of showing the extraneous trailing zeroes, it would just print:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="10"/>
```

Anyone run into something like this before?

Comment: 6 years later and this is still a problem. The initial value output should be subject to the `decimal_places` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using {{form}} or {{form.field_name}} and thus can't do:

```
 <input type="text" name="foo" value="{{value | floatformat}}"/>
```

If so, you can loop through the fields in the constructor method and round them as you see fit, ie:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    for key in self.fields:
        try:
            self.fields[key].initial = round(self.fields[key].initial, 2)
        except:
            pass
```

Obviously you'll want to modify the actual rounding line as per your needs - you can imitate the floatformat behavior if you want.